# My RPi suddenly stopped setting the default gateway

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have a RPi 3 running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)`. The last update of the OS was a few years ago. It is powering a home dashboard and there are no changes on it except for automatic security patches.

It was working great until two weeks ago (obviously it stopped working correctly when I was away from home) and I see that the issue is that **the gateway is not set *anymore* by DHCP**.

Due to its unique usage, the OS is not modified and the wireless networking was set once at update time via IIRC `raspi-config` (everything was working fine for years).

What I receive via DHCP is fine and expected:

```
broadcast_address='192.168.10.255'
classless_static_routes='192.168.27.64/27 192.168.10.1'
dhcp_lease_time='3600'
dhcp_message_type='5'
dhcp_rebinding_time='3150'
dhcp_renewal_time='1800'
dhcp_server_identifier='192.168.10.4'
domain_name='swtk.info'
domain_name_servers='192.168.10.4'
host_name='rpi-dash'
ip_address='192.168.10.125'
network_number='192.168.10.0'
ntp_servers='192.168.10.1'
routers='192.168.10.1'
subnet_cidr='24'
subnet_mask='255.255.255.0'
dhcp6_client_id='0001000128281290b827eb0b5a5d'
dhcp6_fqdn='rpi-dash.xxx.info'
dhcp6_fqdn_flags='S'
dhcp6_info_refresh_time='86400'
dhcp6_name_servers='2a01:e0a:407:d3c0:7840:efff:fe3d:f4fe'
dhcp6_server_id='000100012be41cc07a40ef3df4fe'
```

Note the `routers` option is there.

I however do not see the gateway being set:

```
root@rpi-dash ~# ip r
192.168.10.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.10.125 metric 303
192.168.27.64/27 via 192.168.10.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.10.125 metric 303
```

The IPs are set up correctly

```
root@rpi-dash ~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enxb827eb0b5a5d: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:0b:5a:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:5e:0f:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.125/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 3047sec preferred_lft 2597sec
    inet6 2a01:e0a:407:d3c0:56a7:e06d:565a:c8b4/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 85843sec preferred_lft 85843sec
    inet6 fe80::891d:e393:7ab2:ad60/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I can manually fix the issue of the default gateway but it will be gone at the next reboot:

```
root@rpi-dash ~# ping lemonde.fr
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
root@rpi-dash ~# ip route add default via 192.168.10.1 dev wlan0
root@rpi-dash ~# ping lemonde.fr
PING lemonde.fr (151.101.2.137) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.2.137 (151.101.2.137): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=4.26 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.2.137 (151.101.2.137): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=6.50 ms
^C
--- lemonde.fr ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.261/5.379/6.498/1.118 ms
```

The DHCP configuration is the one by default

```
root@rpi-dash ~# grep -v "^#" /etc/dhcpcd.conf | sort | uniq
clientid
hostname
option classless_static_routes
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option interface_mtu
option ntp_servers
option rapid_commit
persistent
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
```

Adding `option routers` does not fix the issue.

Finally, `/etc/network` is the stock one, with

```
root@rpi-dash ~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
root@rpi-dash ~# ls /etc/network/interfaces.d
root@rpi-dash ~#
```

**To summarize**: I have no idea why the gateway is not set (despite having been set without problems for years and until last week). If there is no obvious answer, I will end up manually setting the extra route somewhere but I would prefer i) to understand what the problem is and ii) to fix it correctly to avoid magical solutions.

Comment: @Milliways: to answer your questions:  I installed the RPi just to power a dashboard so it was a stock install without any tinkering. I use root because I am old-fashioned, the 30 years of Linux administration in an amateur way probably does not help. Finally, I do not have backups for this RPi because worst case I will reinstall it from scratch and the content will come via a CI/CD pipe.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a weird choice in Debian to stop setting a gateway when a classless static route is received. I found the information at https://askubuntu.com/questions/767002/dhcp-connection-does-not-set-default-gateway-automatically

I indeed added an extra route some time ago (probably matching the moment where I saw the issue). My fix was to manually add the gateway as part of my post boot script. This is not ideal but it works.